# The differentiable equation satisfies the equation...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Struggling with the following, I don't know what to google to get help so I figured, I can ask here. This is translated, so sorry if some parts don't make sense.

The differentiable function $y(x)$ satisfies the equation:

$\sin{(y(x))} + 8xy(x) = 0$ 
and 
$y(0) = 3\pi$

then evaluate $y´(0) $ .

I wish I could be more extensive in what I have tried, but I honestly I don't know where to start. I would really appreciate some pointers or something I can google. Cheers.

Comment: Supposed to be y´(0). Fixed.

Comment: Differentiate the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the implicit derivative of the equation with respect to $y(x)$ gives $$y'(x)\cdot(\cos(y(x))+8x)+8y(x)=0$$So, $$y'(0)\cdot(\cos(3\pi))+24\pi=0$$$$-y'(0)+24\pi=0$$$$y'(0)=24\pi$$